# Chrome Extension: inserting elements to page using NodeList data

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm new to creating chrome extensions and what I want to do is to insert elements in specific locations on a page by using a element's class name. I know when I do a

```
document.getElementsByClassName("List-Item");
```

It gives me a NodeList. What I want to do is get this list and overlay information on each item on the list with my meta-data. But trying to loop through the node list won't work i.e

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.style.cssText = 'padding: 5px; position: absolute; color: white; left: 0px; top: 0px;      background: green; height: 50px; width: 50px; z-index: 9999';
div.innerHTML = 'Chrome Plugin Success!';

var foo = document.getElementsByClassName("List-Item");
for(var i = 0; i < foo.length; i++) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("card-content")[i].appendChild(div);
}
```

Can some one point me in the right way please?

Comment: Those appear to be different classes.  Yet, you access that of .card-content as were it assumed identical in length to .List-Item.  Additionally, you're inserting the same element over and over again, but that's only going to move it around.  Are you trying to make copies?  To make copies, use `div.cloneNode(true)`.

Comment: Yes i am trying to make copies, i will adjust my code to see if that works better.

Comment: what is your problem exactly??

Comment: My problem was that i wasn't able to inject the html i wanted on certain places on screen. Thanks to ca2longria, realized that I was just moving a singular div element around. 

My new problem is how do I inject the div elements to new dynamically loaded "card-content" when i scroll down the page? 

I am using the `run_at: "document_end"` on my manifest.json but isn't working